# Git repository for multiple Linux users

Tags: linux, git

after reading some of topics I still cannot find solution for this problem.

Lets say this is my infrastructure:
Two types of servers: dev and prod
Two types of user: dev-user and prod-user
Both in same group: users

Both types of servers share one GPFS filesystem with all repositories. And when dev-user clones existing repository, prod-user cannot pull, push or even edit existing files.

How to approach this issue? Methods with core.sharedrepository set to group did not help.

Comment: There's no need to share one repo. Each user can (and probably should) clone their own copy. Git is a DVCS (distributed version control system).

Comment: There is two Linux users but just one real user, I as a admin access GPFS repos from different server types and as different users. Thats the problem because keeping repos on GPFS is easiest way to keep them everywhere up to date. Example above is just an example, I have hundreds of servers and dozen of users to use same repos from different locations.

Comment: Yes, but as you've discovered, it hurts when you do that. So don't do that, even though it makes *other* things easier.